# What word describes 'reconnect and continue' a previous correspondence?

Tags: word-request

I had a correspondence with an office that ended some time ago. Now I want to reconnect and continue from where I left the previous correspondence. My mind tells me the word Resurrect, i.e. resurrecting the previous correspondence but I know this is not appropriate word. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You would be **resuming** your correspondence.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/resume) defines *resume* as follows:

> Begin again or continue after a pause or interruption.